# Compose page from multiple controllers' actions outputs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

this is sort of an architectural-philosophical question :)

Image you want to create very very simple modular MVC-based "CMS". In fact, the only thing you want it to do, is that you can specify (XML for example) structure of every page with something like this (pseudolang):

```
Use layout: Subpage.cshtml
For section "Header" (placeholder in layout) render controller "Header", action "SubpageHeader"
For section "LeftCol" render controller "Menu" action "MainMenu"
For section "Content" render controller "Articles" action "List"
etc.
```

So, what is the elegant and recommended way to do this? I can think of 2 ways now:

Option 1:

Define own route, which will catch desired URLs and will create own MyMvcHandler for this requests. In this handler, processing would not instantiate controller (there is not one "main"), instead it will read the "page structure configuration" (example above), instantiate all required controllers.. but i am not sure, what to do at this point - how to collect results of actions and place them into layout?

Option 2:
Let the default MvcHandler live, and always call some "MasterController" with some default action, which will only return View(layoutPage); In the layout page, implement "page sections" (placeholders for content) as my own helper method, similar to Html.RenderAction - only customized to look into "page structure configuration" and render right controller+action. But this way, the MasterController seems really useless in pipeline to me, is there any way to get rid of him?

Can you think of any better way? Can you see some fundamental up&downs of any of this approaches ? Can you point me to some good resources about this subject? (I cant find any).

Many thanks MVC ninjas ;)

Comment: Assuming Option 2, How do you plan to parse the user-written language from the cms? Wouldn't you need the "MasterController" for that to ensure it's testable? Also, are your sections intended to be predefined or dynamic? Could you use your MasterController to parse out the User-written xml and fill the view-bag with the necessary components? Using Dependency Injection you should be able to achieve something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wanting different controllers and the focus is something like a CMS, I would suggest the following:

1. Have 1 controller which handles the primary URL and layout that the user sees (like your option 2)
2. For each section, have Ajax call backs to get HTML for each section (Header/Menu/Articles/Etc)

Yes, this makes 4 calls,...but the trade offs are great.

Some benefits for example:

1. Each section can now have independent cache headers. (ex. the layout can be cached for days/weeks, instead of on-modified)
2. Each section can be independently refreshed without the client navigating or refreshing the page.
3. Since each section is treated independently, SignalR can be used to process live updates if desired.
4. The sections (assuming they might also get further divided) can be shared across pages. (ex. the articles can be reused where applicable on multiple screens,...and also falling under the same caching benefits as benefit #1)
5. Alterations in each section can be made via parameters if required while refreshing each content piece.
6. Each section/controller/action can be easily manipulated to pass back Json instead of HTML if desired so the client side can enhance the functional experience.  (this is assuming that you aren't doing client side MVC with a framework like knockout)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Master Pages are a simpler way to achieve the goal. Master pages can be used to share common content across multiple pages in your application.  Here is a link to the ASP.net MVC web page for [Creating Page Layouts with View Master Pages](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-page-layouts-with-view-master-pages-cs)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is possible, because of the method you mention (which is imo more flexible than the section approach):

```
Html.RenderAction("AnyAction", "AnyController")
```

I think the biggest problem with that concept is state. If you go this route, and the "AnyController" needs to maintain state, you need to formalize that. Otherwise: who's going to be authorative over the querystring and the post variables? And what would you do in case of a variable name clash?

Note that ASP.NET classic already somehow "solved" this issue with its postback state field. It assigns unique ID's to all page elements and puts that in a tree. Biggest downside to that is that it quickly can become bloated and inefficient, like is often the case with ASP.NET classic.

You can also have a look at how this problem is solved in other CMS's, like N2CMS (disclaimer: I have little experience with any other CMS). I think it's implementation somehow resembles your second option. You specify within the CMS which blocks go into which area's, and the system then calls all views. The difference is that for subviews, the content model for a view is figured out by the system, not by a specific controller, though you could change that conceptually (not sure how feasible in practice) by invoking RenderAction instead of RenderView. But in that case, you're at the state discussion again.